# Can Xcode build multi-module apps without having to use dynamic linking?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linker

I have a workspace containing an iOS app MyApp, a static library MyAppCore, and a static library MyLogging. MyLogging is a dependency of both MyApp and MyAppCore. MyAppCore is a dependency of MyApp. This makes MyLogging in a sense "included" twice when building MyApp. Everything is written in Swift and none of the modules are pre-compiled - we have the source for all the modules in the workspace. Now for the big question:

Is there a way to get Xcode to build MyApp without having to resort to dynamic linking?

This is a simplified example and our real use case is a bigger app with almost 100 modules. From what we've seen in the past, dynamic linking adds significantly to app startup time.

Comment: This probably isn't an answer, but why not simply create a *Scheme* to do this? You can order the builds. As for app startup time, I'm pretty sure that's not at all related to Xcode. For that, have you tried *app thinning*? (That's not Xcode, it's App Store Connect more than anything.)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid dynamic linking? Seems that is solves the linking problem quite well.

Comment: @Cristik Because for each dynamically linked framework you add to an iOS app, the startup time becomes slower. We tested having many dynamically linked frameworks before and it added over 1 second to app startup time which is unacceptable. Apple has recommended not having more than 6 frameworks for this reason.

Comment: I remember once trying something like this, with weak linking of the static libraries, unfortunately I wasn't able to reach to satisfactory results...

Comment: There is only one solution for this - include all sources into main app target.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Just tested with Xcode13, and seems the linking works even if the dependency graph would result in the same library being linked twice.

Tested with 3 Swift-only targets: MyApp, MyAppLogging, MyAppCore, with MyAppLogging being consumed by both MyApp, as well as MyAppCore, this meaning both linking to the library, as well as instantiating a class from the MyAppLogging library.

Seems things have changed since the last time I checked on this, and Xcode is now able to detect situations like this and avoid the binary duplication, which would fail the build.

Note that both libraries and the app were configured from scratch, so this might not work as well on an existing project.

MyApp build phases:
[image]

MyAppCore build phases:
[image]

#### Original answer below

---

No, this cannot be done with static linking. Static linking means the binary of the `MyLogging` library will be added to both the binary of the `MyAppCore` library, as well your app binary. And this, as you noticed, leads to duplicate symbols.

A somewhat quick fix is to avoid this kind of dependencies, and have only the app link to all static libraries.

This requires injecting some kind of dependencies to the other libraries, which implies configuring all libraries at startup.

For your example `MyAppCore` could expose a

```swift
public var logger: CoreLoggerProtocol! // IUO for easier use, and to make sure it's injected, otherwise the app will crash at first logger usage
```

, which gets set from your app at launch time:

```swift
extension MyLogging.Logger: CoreLoggerProtocol { }

MyAppCore.logger = MyLogging.Logger.shared
```

The above implies that `CoreLoggerProtocol` has the same methods as `MyLogging.Logger`, or at least the ones consumed by `MyAppCore`. A similar approach can be applied to other libraries that need logging capabilities.

The benefits of this approach:

- static libraries all the way
- low coupling between modules
- increased testability of the `MyAppCore` module, as unit tests can seamlessly inject their own fake logger
- mistakes, like forgetting to inject the logger, are easily caught during a quick testing session, but unit tests can also be written to make sure the app startup code injects the dependencies through all libraries.

Comment: As I understand it, if my example project was a C program and we built static archives (.a files) for MyAppCore and MyLogging it would be possible to link everything statically without duplicated symbols. It's interesting that this is not possible with Xcode in Swift, I wish it was. Thank you for this answer, it's technically correct and will allow us to use static libraries all the way!

Comment: It's an interesting solution. I'd say the protocols in our case serve the same purpose as the header files do in a C program, they define the interface of code that's external to the piece of code being compiled. So we can compile MyAppCore without linking MyLogging because we have the interface definition in protocols.

Comment: It's not an optimal solution in my opinion and I would rather have Xcode link everything correctly with no duplication, without placeholder protocols. But I will accept your answer and reward the bounty in 24 hours if there are no better answers.

Comment: @quad16 agreed, not a nice solution, however, looks like with Xcode 13 the link works even with the dependency graph from the question. Check my updated answer.